# Como fazer um menu-div aparecer quando clicado em um botao?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Estou tentando fazer um menu semelhante a este:

[Clique aqui para ver o exemplo do menu](http://www.zuperstores.com/wizard/photography/index.html#panelBlock8)

O que fiz, coloquei uma `div` por cima da outra utiliando o `position:absolute` e ocultei a `div` responsável pelo menu com um `display:none`e no JS estou tentando aplicar uma efeito que a faça ser exibida quando clicada num botão, assim como no exemplo do site. Entretanto, sem sucesso.

Não necessariamente precisa ser com JS. Pode ser com JS, JQuery, CSS3(creio que isso possa ser feito com ele também) etc.

Enfim, Existe uma "forma melhor" de fazer isso?
Onde estou errando?

```js
 function exibe(){
  

  document.getElementById('nav').body= ??
 }
```

```css
  html, body{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
  }

  #principal{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }

  #nav{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 10;
  }
  #menu{
   
   z-index: 11;
   position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
 <div id="principal">   
   <button id="menu" onclick="exibe()"> MENU </button> 
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr1br.png"  style="width:100%; height:100%">
 </div>


 <div id="nav">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQXbV.png"  style="height:100%">
 </div>
```

Comment: em resumo, você quer fazer um menu off canvas?

Comment: @TobyMosque Bom, sim e não. Não estou fazendo para um site funcional. Estou fazendo este efeito com duas `divs` que possuem imagens de background. Sobre o Off canvas, estou conhecendo agora, baseado no que você disse rsrs Pesquisei e realmente é este tipo de efeito que quero, porém queria saber como faço isso na mão. Estou querendo aprender a fazer as coisas por conta própria e me livrar dos frameworks. Se você ou alguem puder me ajudar, ficarei super grato ;)

Comment: Bom eu usaria o BootStrap ou Materialize, mas vc pode dar uma estudada no jQuery Animate http://api.jquery.com/animate ou 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: Links bastante úteis, principalmente o da **w3schools** por exibir o código rodando, irei olhar um a um, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

olha, para fazer um menu `off-canvas`, você vai precisar de duas `div`s, uma para o `conteudo` que irá ocupar toda a tela e outra para o `menu`, o menu ficará oculta em uma area não visivel.

Para ocultar o nav, iremos usar `position: absolute`, atribuir um valor negativo ao `left`, este deve ser igual ou superior ao `width` do mesmo, para exibir o menu, basta atualizar o valor do `left` para 0px.

Para fazer a animação, podemos usar uma `transition`.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var showMenu = document.getElementById("showMenu");
var hideMenu = document.getElementById("hideMenu");
showMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  nav.classList.add("show");
});

hideMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  nav.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;  
}

#conteudo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;  
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  overflow: auto;
}

#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -255px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 250px;  
  background-color: gainsboro;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  
  transition: left 0.5s linear;
}

#nav.show {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
  <input id="showMenu" type="button" value="Exibir Menu" />
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <input id="hideMenu" type="button" value="Ocultar Menu" />
</div>
```

Comment: por que o `-1`?

Comment: Perfeito! Uma lógica bem objetiva, pensei de duas formas distintas mas a sua foi bem mais simples, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Votei como positivo. Se foi como negativo, foi erro meu. Já corrigi.